# llamar a objeto con nombre variable excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Quiero hacer un bloque para llamar a varios botones según una variable. Mi idea (que no es correcta) sería esta:

```
Private Sub Eliminar()
    num = Range("z1").Value
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("figura" & num).Select
    Selection.Delete
    CmdEliminar & 'num'.Enabled = False
    CmdGenerar & 'num'.Enabled = True
    CmdComparar  & 'num'.Enabled = False
    CmdComparar & 'num'.Caption = "SEPARAR"
End Sub

Private Sub CmdEliminar4_Click()
    Range("z1").Value = 4
    Eliminar
End Sub
```

Se que hay alguna forma no muy distinta a la expuesta para poder hacerlo pero no lo recuerdo.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. ¿Qué tipo de control son los botones que quieres cambiar? ¿Están insertados en una hoja o son botones dentro de un formulario?

Comment: esta en una hoja

Comment: Si es un botón en una hoja, que yo sepa, estará insertado como objeto `Shape`, no como un `CommandButton`. Entonces no tiene las propiedad `Enabled` por ejemplo. Tendrás que hacer un bucle que pasee por todas tus formas, y usando el nombre, entonces hacerla visible/invisible

Comment: con el shape no tengo problema, me funciona perfectamente. Es con los botones CmdComparar, CmdEliminar y CmdGenerar. Tengo cuatro bloques de botones, y por evitar codigo quería hacer un módulo común

Comment: ¿Lo que pretendes hacer es una concatenacion con CmdEliminar & num para que excel vea algo asi CmdEliminar2, por ejemplo? ¿y así poder hacer una funcion que llame a todos los botones que tengan el mismo num?

Answer (score 1):

He creado este ejemplo para ti porque creo que es lo que buscas.

Hay tres bloques con tres botones cada uno.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si pulsas un botón se ejecuta solamente lo que hayas programado para ese botón. En este caso cada botón muestra solamente un mensaje con la identificacion **A1**, **B3**, **C2** según el botón que hayas pulsado.

Si pulsas el botón **General 1**, **2** o **3** el código de ese botón llama a ***Private Sub f_ButtonABC*** con dos argumentos que representan el número de bloque **1**, **2** o **3** y la letra **A**, **B** o **C**.
En este caso la funcion es **Private Sub** pero funciona con cualquier definición que pongas (**Public Function**, **Sub**, **Private Sub**,...) siempre y cuando lo hagas en el objeto Hoja junto con el codigo **Private Sub** de los botones.

Si lo que deseas es poner la función en un módulo, que es lo suyo, no podrás declararla como **Private** porque te dará error. Cualquier otra definición funcionará perfectamente.

Como ya nos habremos dado cuenta la línea estrella de este código es:
***Application.Run stringConcatenado***
que nos permite llamar a una Función o un Sub/Macro con un string concatenado.

*Es muy importante que ese string lleve incluido el nombre de la hoja*

```
Private Sub ButtonA1_Click()
    MsgBox "A1"
End Sub
Private Sub ButtonB1_Click()
    MsgBox "B1"
End Sub
Private Sub ButtonC1_Click()
    MsgBox "C1"
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonA2_Click()
    MsgBox "A2"
End Sub
Private Sub ButtonB2_Click()
    MsgBox "B2"
End Sub
Private Sub ButtonC2_Click()
    MsgBox "C2"
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonA3_Click()
    MsgBox "A3"
End Sub
Private Sub ButtonB3_Click()
    MsgBox "B3"
End Sub
Private Sub ButtonC3_Click()
    MsgBox "C3"
End Sub

Private Sub General1_Click()
    f_ButtonABC 1, "A"
End Sub

Private Sub General2_Click()
    f_ButtonABC 2, "B"
End Sub

Private Sub General3_Click()
    f_ButtonABC 3, "C"
End Sub

Private Sub f_ButtonABC(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal letra As String)

    'Si quieres ejecutar el codigo con número index fijo y letra variable
    MsgBox "Index fijo y letra variable"
    Application.Run "Hoja1.ButtonA" & index & "_Click"
    Application.Run "Hoja1.ButtonB" & index & "_Click"
    Application.Run "Hoja1.ButtonC" & index & "_Click"

    'Si quieres ejecutar el codigo en función del index con letra fija
    MsgBox "Función del index con letra fija "
    For i = 1 To 3
        Application.Run "Hoja1.Button" & letra & i & "_Click"
    Next

    'Si quieres ejecutar el codigo pasando por todos los botones
    MsgBox "Cödigo pasando por todos los botones"
    iChr = 0
    While iChr < 3
        For i = 1 To 3
            Application.Run "Hoja1.Button" & Chr(65 + iChr) & i & "_Click"
        Next
        iChr = iChr + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo buscaba algo similar lo mío era mediante un un checkbox que lo llame checkboxtodo dando click a este checkbox tenia que marcarme a varios checkbox según el valor de una celda.
aca les muestro el codigo:
[image: Objetos en vba]

```
Private Sub CheckBoxtodo_Click()
Dim ctrl As OLEObject
Dim check As MSForms.CheckBox
If Me.CheckBoxtodo = True Then
    For Each ctrl In Worksheets(2).OLEObjects
        If TypeOf ctrl.Object Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        Set check = ctrl.Object
          For i = 1 To Hoja2.Range("B3").Value
                If LCase(check.Caption) = "" & i Then
                    check.Enabled = True
                    ctrl.Visible = True
                    check.Value = True
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next
Else
    For Each ctrl In Worksheets(2).OLEObjects
        If TypeOf ctrl.Object Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        Set check = ctrl.Object
          For i = 1 To 28
                If LCase(check.Caption) = "" & i Then
                    check.Enabled = True
                    ctrl.Visible = True
                    check.Value = False
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next
End If
    Range("H3").Select
End Sub
```